# Wordpress Flex Slider Shifting Layout

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

My flex slider on my wordpress site keeps shifting the layout content below it when it initially loads, such that all the site content moves upwards and then back into position when the slider loads the image.

Kindly advise soonest on as to how to resolve this issue.

The website can be found below and the slider is on the homepage.

http://www.riverdalep.com/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 1st and 2nd your image in slider is error => slider don't loading height for slider. Check and add Image again. Good luck.

[image: I see your Image Error here]

Comment: Hi DinhCode,
Well spotted and thank you !
I just removed those particular properties from the slider, even after re-uploading image, there was still an issue.